# Creating a deterministic finite automata

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata

I need to create a non-empty DFA over the language {a,b,c} with the following properties:

1. First symbol is a.
2. Has an even number of b's.
3. Last symbol is a c.

I was just wondering, should I create 3 seperate automatas, and then combine them using intersections, or should I just create the one, and if that is the case, how can it has an even number of b's? I know I can alternate the states, but not sure how to do it with it all combined.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to do this with 3 states.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yeah I know I have to start with a, and then when i go to a state from there, how can I make b have an even number of states, because an a,b, or c could be inserted into the automata after the first state.

Comment: You need one state to represent "an odd number of b", and another state to represent "an even number of b".  Each time you receive a b, transition from one state to the other.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Would this work? https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1kc9vl98kne0fw/IMG-20120520-00004.jpg

Comment: I think I have misunderstood your language definition; I assumed you could only have strings of the form "abbbbbbbbbbc", but are you saying that you can also have e.g. "abbbaabc"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No you are right, I have done it wrong, one second let me just amend my answer and I'll show you.

Comment: BTW, if this is homework, you should add the "homework" tag to your question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No it's not homework, I'm just doing some past questions. This is what I got: https://www.dropbox.com/s/deuue48dpb15sbr/IMG-20120520-00005.jpg

Comment: You now have two edges from (1) labelled "c"...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I know, obviously that would be incorrect, but I'm not sure how to solve that.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your automaton (assuming that 0 is even and therefor 0 b's is ok):

```
[start](a) -> [1]
[start](b,c,<eoi>) -> [reject]

[1](a) -> [1]
[1](<eoi>) -> [reject]

[1](c) -> [2]
[1](b) -> [3]

[2](<eoi>) -> [accept]
[2](c) -> [2]
[2](a) -> [1]
[2](b) -> [3]

[3](<eoi>) -> [reject]
[3](a,c) -> [3]
[3](b)->[1]
```

Where  is "end-of-input".

State 1: even number of b's, the last symbol processed not c.
State 2: even number of b's, the last symbol processed is c.
State 3: odd number of b's.

Comment: It did not say anywhere that it was homework. In any case, it was much easier just to implement it than to try explaining how it's done. I hope OP will learn from it.

Comment: Fair enough.  But what would probably be more helpful is explaining the general procedure for arriving at such a solution.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot It's not homework.. On the second line, what does this mean? (b,c,<eoi>)

Comment: @malenkiy_scot I don't think your answer is correct, because it doesn't accept a word such as abcbc

Comment: [start] is the initial state. [start](b,c,<eoi>) means that if in the initial state you get `b`,`c`, or `end-of-input` - you go into [reject] state (a state which on any input transitions into itself and is not an acceptance state).

Comment: Ok, you mean that 'even number of b's' does not mean 'only b's', but other symbols are also OK. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Yep that's what i meant

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Would this be right? https://www.dropbox.com/s/u67pg9kicwpe435/IMG-20120520-00006.jpg

Comment: It looks exactly like what I've written. So I think that's fine (the initial state is not accepting, of course).

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]
Your required DFA is shown in the attached image [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K3Xw.jpg

Now let us try to understand how the DFA is constructed.
Initial state- 'q0'
Now we take a on 'q0' for making the starting symbol of string 'a'.
After that we want to construct our DFA which contains even number of 'b's' for that we take b on 'q1','q2'. And our required DFA has last symbol is a 'c'. So we take 'c' on 'q3'. The final state is 'q4'.
Now we see transition of each state.
On 'q0' we take string symbol 'a' for starting symbol and we goes to state 'q1'.
If we take string symbols 'b' and 'c' on state 'q0' we goes to the state 'q5'.
If we take 'a','c' on state 'q1' then we stay in the same state 'q1'.
Now we take 'b' on 'q1' then we goes to the state 'q2'.
In the constructing DFA we have odd number of 'b's' ie 1. But we take even number of 'b's'.
If we take 'a','c' on state 'q2' then we stay in the same state 'q2'.
If we take string symbol 'b' on state 'q2' then we goes to the state 'q3'.
If we take 'a'on state 'q3' then we stay in the same state 'q3'.
If we take string symbol 'b' on state 'q3' then we goes to the state 'q2'.
If we take string symbol 'c' on state 'q3' then we goes to the state 'q4' which is final state. Because in that DFA we follow the properties which we required.
If we take string symbol 'b' on state 'q4' then we goes to the state 'q2'.
If we take string symbol 'a' on state 'q4' then we goes to the state 'q3'.
This is our required DFA.